# copy as long as value does not change in R

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I have a data frame which contain multiple rows, see example.

```
df <- data.frame(rbind(c('1','CAR','Jan'),
                       c('2','3','4'),
                       c('5','6','7'),
                       c('8','CAR','Feb'),
                       c('9','10', '11'),
                       c('12','13','14')))
```

I would like to copy the value in which comes after CAR (Jan and Feb) and copy it in a new column X4 until CAR is coming again. The number of rows is not all the time the same between the CARs, the number of columns are the same.

The data should look like this

```
data.frame(rbind(c('1','CAR','Jan','Jan' ),
                     c('2','3','4','Jan'),
                     c('5','6','7','Jan'),
                     c('8','CAR','Feb','Feb'),
                     c('9','10','11','Feb'),
                     c('11','12','12','Feb')))
```

I have tried different options (ifelse, if, for loop), but none of them provides the right result.

Would you have any hints on how to solve this?
Thanks in advance
Eric

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an uglier, base-R version of David's answer:

```
df$X4 <- unlist(tapply(
  df$X3,
  cumsum(df$X2=="CAR"),
  function(x){y <- levels(x)[x[1]]; rep(y,length(x))}
))
```

Comment: Showing how bad it is working without `data.table` can also help :)

Comment: You could use `ave` `with(df, ave(X3, cumsum(X2=='CAR'), FUN=function(x) x[1]))`

Comment: @akrun Ah, never learned `ave`, but that does look a little less ugly. I only learned to use `tapply` recently. I guess neither of them (nor `by` or `aggregate`, et al) really has an practical use for me, since I'm always using `data.table`s

Comment: THANKS A LOT! it works, I tried with zoo earlier, but for some reason did not manage.

Comment: @Eric Glad to hear it! I hope you consider `data.table` (as in the other answers) in the future. Its syntax and speed are pretty handy. `dplyr` (in one of the answers) is also certainly less ugly here.

Comment: @Frank, will sure do. never considered setDT. thanks again to all, really saved my day

Answer (score 7):

Here's a another `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, X4 := X3[1L], by = cumsum(X2 == "CAR")]
df
#    X1  X2  X3  X4
# 1:  1 CAR Jan Jan
# 2:  2   3   4 Jan
# 3:  5   6   7 Jan
# 4:  8 CAR Feb Feb
# 5:  9  10  11 Feb
# 6: 12  13  14 Feb
```

We could also do a similar thing using `dplyr` (but it will add an `indx` column too)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(indx = cumsum(X2 == "CAR")) %>%
  mutate(X4 = X3[1L])
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(df)[X2=='CAR', X4:= X3][, X4:= na.locf(X4)]
#   X1  X2  X3  X4
#1:  1 CAR Jan Jan
#2:  2   3   4 Jan
#3:  5   6   7 Jan
#4:  8 CAR Feb Feb
#5:  9  10  11 Feb
#6: 12  13  14 Feb
```